# List comprehension for matplotlib methods

Tags: python, list, matplotlib, label, list-comprehension

```
ax[0].set_ylabel("Valor")
ax[1].set_ylabel("Máximos y Mínimos")
ax[2].set_ylabel("Fear and Greed")
ax[3].set_ylabel("Put Call Ratio")
ax[4].set_ylabel("T10Y2Y")
ax[5].set_ylabel("RASI")
ax[6].set_ylabel("Oscilador Mcclellan")
```

I'm trying to put all of these in a list comprehension, something like this but doesn't work:

```
[[ax[i].set_ylabel(x) for i in range(7)] for x in ['Valor', 'Máximos y Mínimos', 'Fear & Greed', 'Put Call Ratio', 'T10Y2Y', 'RASI', 'Oscilador Mcclellan']]
```

Can't get the number on ax[] with the exact string for each one. Any ideas?

Comment: why not use regular for? list comprehension works when you want to create another list, not for plotting

Comment: It's a pretty big graph and I'm trying to reduce lines of coding.

Comment: It's not considered good practice to use a list comprehension only for side effects. If you don't need the resulting list, it's better to just use a `for` loop. Only takes 1 more line while being much more semantic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for `enumerate`:

```
[ax[i].set_ylabel(x) for i, x in enumerate(['Valor', 'Máximos y Mínimos', 'Fear & Greed', 'Put Call Ratio', 'T10Y2Y', 'RASI', 'Oscilador Mcclellan'])]
```